# Use of if [[ ]] (bash)

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm not very familiar with bash scripting, and obviously I'm not using if [[ ]] like I should.
Indeed, when I write this:

```
dossier=( NEG POS A B C D E F G H M)  
for element in "${dossier[@]}"; do
    if [[ $element==M ]]; then
           [...]
        fi
done
```

It executes the instructions in the if for every element, considering NEG,POS... being equal to M. I guess I'm not using the good syntax!
Thank you for your answers
H.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add spaces:

```
if [[ $element==M ]]; then
```

To

```
if [[ $element == M ]]; then
```